# GTK+ (2.0) - signal "clicked" on GtkEntry?

Tags: gtk, signals, gtk2, click, gtkentry

I'm testing some signals with GTK+ 2.0. I'm looking for a way to get a signal emitted when I click on a GtkEntry.

```
if (widgets_info[i].action & IG_INPUT)
    {
      widget->frame[i] = gtk_entry_new_with_max_length(MAX_INPUT_LENGTH);
      gtk_entry_set_text(widget->frame[i], widgets_info[i].text);
      catch_signal(widget->frame[i], MY_SIGNAL, &change_entry, widget);
    }
```

I have a pre-selected text in my entry (`widgets_info[i].text`) and i want this text to disappear if the user click on my GtkEntry.

Does someone know what is this signal?

*(Sorry for my English)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [focus-in-event](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-focus-in-event), note that you must enable focus-tracking as described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The button-press-event signal should do what you need:
http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event

However, in GTK+ 3, GtkEntry now supports this idea of placeholder text, so you don't need to implement it yourself:
http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-placeholder-text